# Ensuring a shell script to be executed as lsf job only

Tags: shell, lsf

I have shell script and want to disable it's execution as normal job. It should be executed only as bjob in LSF

How can I make sure this with in script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lsfError="**ERROR: Local jobs disabled. Please run through LSF only --"
lsfExit=2
lsfLog="$(getent passwd $(id -un) | cut -d: -f6)/.lsbatch/.lsf_${LSB_JOBID}.log"
echo "**INFO: Verifying as LSF job ..."
sleep 2s
if [ -z "$LSB_JOBID" ]; then
  echo "$lsfError"; exit $lsfExit
elif [[ "$(bjobs $LSB_JOBID 2>&1)" =~ "not found" ]]; then
  echo "**ERROR: Job $LSB_JOBID doesn't exist" > $lsfLog
  echo "$lsfError"; exit $lsfExit
elif [[ "$(bjobs -o 'command' -noheader $LSB_JOBID 2>&1)" != "$0" ]]; then
  echo "**ERROR: Command not matched $(bjobs -o "command" -noheader $LSB_JOBID 2>&1) != $0" > $lsfLog
  echo "$lsfError"; exit $lsfExit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

LSF will set some environment variables in the job environment, such as `$LSB_JOBID`.  You could write the script to check for that this environment variable is defined. If not, explain that the script should only be run as an LSF job and then exit.

Comment: I could able to get job id. what are other environment variables LSF will set?, Is there any documentation of these variables

Comment: You can find the full list [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSETD4_9.1.3/lsf_config_ref/lsf_envars_job_exec.dita?lang=en)

Comment: But still user can set these variables on his terminal and execute script without launching as a bjob. Script could not able to determine whether these variables are from LSF or inherited from terminal

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could expect that an LSF job is started by `res`, so you can check if there is a `res` process in the same process group, something like

```
_pgid=`ps -o pgid --no-headers -p $$`
ps -o comm,pgid --no-headers | grep -qE '^res\s+'${_pgid// /}'$' || { echo "Must submit as LSF job!"; exit 1; }
```

Comment: I have added -u $(id -un) to ps command. It exited when not lsf.
But if there is res process for every bjob, how can we identify which res belongs to which bjob

Comment: I guess you could use the job's process group to identify the `res` instance related to this specific job; please see the edit.